# I have a MD Array, which I need to run a function on to return a result where if $res=1 i have to print $spec or else not

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
db=array();

for($i=1;$i<=n;$i++){

     $db[]=array(
          'spec'=>$spec,
              'res'=>$res
      );

 }
```

> Array, which I need to run a function on to return a result where if
>   $res=1 i have to print $spec or else not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($db as $item) 
{
if($item['res']==1) echo $item['spec'];
}
```